# Javac does not recognize classes that are in the same directory

Tags: java, compiler-errors, classpath, javac

I am trying to compile my Java program which relies on external libraries. The program compiles without errors in the IDE.  Upon compiling in a terminal, I am faced with the compiler not recognizing the code that I have written. **All files are in the same directory.** I am using a Makefile.

The following is the javac call and the resulting errors that arise. All Java and Jar files are in the current directory.

```
    $ javac -cp "./*" Driver.java
    Driver.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
            DataSetProcessor processor = new DataSetProcessor();
            ^
      symbol:   class DataSetProcessor
      location: class Driver
    Driver.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
            DataSetProcessor processor = new DataSetProcessor();
                                             ^
      symbol:   class DataSetProcessor
      location: class Driver
    Driver.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
    HashMap<Integer, Dealer> map = processor.getDealerVehicleRelationship(dataSetID, vehicleIDsList);
                     ^
      symbol:   class Dealer
      location: class Driver
    3 errors
```

Dealer.java & DataSetProcessor.java are in the current directory.

Can someone please explain to be what my problem is? I can't understand it.

Comment: SOLUTION: I have changed the compiler call to `javac -cp lib/commons-io-2.6.jar:lib/json-20180813.jar:. Driver.java`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do the following :

- Put all your libraries in a directory called lib,
- Put all the classes you create in the current directory.
- For the classes you use for jars, you will need import statements
- For the classes you create, you do not need import statements.
- Use the following command to compile :

> $ javac -cp "lib/*:." Driver.java

Comment: I would have thought so, too. However, that results in more errors; all references to the external JARs now cause errors. eg.... Driver.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
  JSONArray vehicleIDsList = processor.getAllVehicleIdsForDataSet(dataSetID);
  symbol:   class JSONArray
  location: class Driver

Comment: Do put all your jars in a directory called `lib` and use `-cp "./lib"` instead.

Comment: When I do that, the program is able to identify the classes that I have written (Dealer.java) but no longer recognizes the JARs.

Comment: Please try with `-cp "./lib/*"`

Comment: This results is the same behavior as the original post. The compiler recognizes the JARs, but fails to recognize DataSetProcessor and Driver. PS. Thank you for you help.

Comment: @SupposedlySleeping, I tested this out on both Mac and Linux and have updated the answer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

My use of the -cp was wrong. I am using Mac; I'm not sure if that is the reason.

The final compiler call is now:

`$ javac -cp lib/commons-io-2.6.jar:lib/json-20180813.jar:. Driver.java`

and the call to run the program is:

`$ java -cp lib/commons-io-2.6.jar:lib/json-20180813.jar:. Driver`